# TypeError: start.endsWith is not a function in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

When I changed my base url from `/` to `window.document.location` its giving me the below error

```
TypeError: start.endsWith is not a function
```

anybody faced the same issue in angular2@2.1.0?

Comment: I had a case issue on mine, I had all lower case.  Still arrived here though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Location is an object, and not a string.

Try `window.document.location.href` instead (which is a string).

Comment: Ohhh, got it. its expecting a string but getting an object and creating problem